# Uncaught TypeError: request.open is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Code:

```
// urlget.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX GET-request example</title>
</head>
<body style='text-align:center'>
    <h1>Loading Web page into DIV</h1>
    <div id='info'>This sentense will be replaced</div>

    <script>
        nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000
        request = new ajaxRequest()
        request.open("GET", "urlget.php?url= amazon.com/gp/aw " + nocache, true)

        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (this.status == 200)
                {
                    if (this.responseText != null)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText
                    }
                    else alert('AJAX error: Data not received')
                }
                else alert("AJAX error: " + this.statusText)
            }
        }
        request.send(null)

        function ajaxRequest()
        {
            try
            {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch(e2)
            {
                try
                {
                    request = new ActivateXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch(e3)
                {
                    request = false
                }
            }
        }
        function ret(request){return request}
        ret(request)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: request.open is not a function

Comment: `ajaxRequest` doesn’t return anything. Why are you using `new` at all? Are you trying to modify `request` globally from within the function?

Answer (score 0):

`request = new ajaxRequest()` is not how you instantiate an AJAX request with JQuery. As such, `request` doesn't become initialized to an XMLHttpRequest object and therefore it has no `open` method.

See **[this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** for JQuery AJAX.